# rails legacy connection handling error when testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

An application is not using multiple databases; in fact it is set as per rails 7.0.8 generation upon application creation.

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: app_name_development

  <<: *default
  database: app_name_test
```

Upon running a controller test with Minitest, the following error emerges.

In addition, the link provided both refers to multiple db contexts (which this isn't) **and** the anchor is not present in the document (in its version for rails 7.1.1)

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Using legacy connection handling is deprecated. Please set
`legacy_connection_handling` to `false` in your application.

The new connection handling does not support `connection_handlers`
getter and setter.

Read more about how to migrate at: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html#migrate-to-the-new-connection-handling
[... points to application_record.rb line 1 as source of problem]
```

application_record.rb has

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

and the application runs as expected, without that specific complaint being logged.

I therefore assume it has something to do with testing and its database, but have no clue where to investigate nor resolve this matter.  One could blindly set `legacy_connection_handling` as suggested, but that still does not explain why, nor the source of the problem. What could be going on here?

Comment: Are there any gems that could be behind it? If you look at the full stack trace does it tell you anything more?

Comment: I had that thought, having added simplecov to the test block.  But even after commenting out non-boilerplate test gems, the error remains signalled (not the test then goes on to complete).  Even with `-b` added to the test command nothing occurs, as the test is not failing per se. This is a rails warning.